# Notifications in Multiple Thread iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, notifications

I have found that when I want to deliver Notifications to particular threads, there is a sample from Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001289-CEGJFDFG

In this article, Apple suggests that using a machport to monitor the thread which we want to process the notification.

```
- (void)processNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([NSThread currentThread] != notificationThread) {
        // Forward the notification to the correct thread.
        [self.notificationLock lock];
        [self.notifications addObject:notification];
        [self.notificationLock unlock];
        [self.notificationPort sendBeforeDate:[NSDate date]
                components:nil
                from:nil
                reserved:0];
    }
    else {
        // Process the notification here;
    }
}
```

My question is: if I get the notification and I use `dispatch_async` to process the notification, does it has a different appearance?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Process the notification here;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simple answer is : no difference

I also noticed the apple suggested link is Updated: 2009-08-18. it seems to already outdated. GCD is a more powerful and convenient way to achieve multi-thread work.